# Polymorphism with operator overloading in Swift

Tags: swift

I've run into an issue with how I expect operator overloading to work in Swift. In particular, I'm wondering about the comparisons at the end of the following code snippet:

```
class Base {
    var val: Int

    init(val: Int) {
        self.val = val
    }
}

class Sub: Base {
    var subVal: Int

    init(subVal: Int, val: Int) {
        self.subVal = subVal
        super.init(val: val)
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> Bool {
    return lhs.val == rhs.val
}

func ==(lhs: Sub, rhs: Sub) -> Bool {
    return lhs.val == rhs.val
        && lhs.subVal == rhs.subVal
}


let obj1 = Sub(subVal: 3, val: 4)
let obj2 = Base(val: 5)
let obj3 = Sub(subVal: 2, val: 4)
let obj4 = Base(val: 4)

obj1 == obj2            //returns false, as expected
obj1 == obj3            //returns false, as expected
obj2 == obj3            //returns false, as expected
obj1 == obj4            //returns true, as expected
obj1 == obj3 as Base    //returns true, why?
obj1 as Base == obj3    //returns true, why?
```

My main issue, as noted is with the behavior of overloaded operators at runtime. I would expect that since `(obj3 as Base)` still has type `Sub` at runtime, that the function taking `lhs` and `rhs` as `Sub` would be invoked. However, this is clearly not the case. Is there a way to have operators behave like this without having to define a `.equals(_)` method or something similar for `Base` and `Sub`?

Comment: Operators are currently statically dispatched. That could change in the future. Check this reply by Chris Lattner for details: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1074064#1074064

Answer (score 1):

Operators work on the type of the declared variable. And albeit a variable of type `Base` can hold an object instance of type `Sub` it is still considered as `Base`. Unless you tell the compiler you want to look upon it as something else (as in `obj3 as Base`).

In the following code snippet I reuse your class definitions, modified the == operator slightly, and added a few cases:

```
func ==(lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> String {
    return "BaseCmp is \( lhs.val == rhs.val )"
}

func ==(lhs: Sub, rhs: Sub) -> String {
    return "SubCmp is \( lhs.val == rhs.val && lhs.subVal == rhs.subVal )"
}

// obj1 & obj3 is indirectly declared as Base
// obj2 & obj4 is indirectly declared as Sub
let obj1 = Sub(subVal: 3, val: 4)
let obj2 = Base(val: 5)
let obj3 = Sub(subVal: 2, val: 4)
let obj4 = Base(val: 4)

obj1 == obj2            // BaseCmp is false
obj1 == obj3            // SubCmp is false
obj2 == obj3            // BaseCmp is false
obj1 == obj4            // BaseCmp is true
obj1 == obj3 as Base    // BaseCmp is true
obj1 as Base == obj3    // BaseCmp is true

// b1, b2, b3 is directly declared as Base
// b2 & b3 holds instances of Sub
var b1 : Base = Base(val: 4)
var b2 : Base = Sub(subVal: 2, val: 4)
var b3 : Base = Sub(subVal: 8, val: 4)

// s1 directly declared as Sub, and holds a Sub
var s1 : Sub = Sub(subVal: 9, val: 4)
// s2 of type Sub, can not hold the more general Base!
// var s2 : Sub = Base(val: 4) // 'Base' is not convertible to 'Sub'

b1 == b2               // BaseCmp is true
b2 == b3               // BaseCmp is true
b2 as Sub == b3 as Sub // SubCmp is false

// Declaration and different types, BaseCmp is used
obj3 == b3          // BaseCmp is true
b2 == s1            // BaseCmp is true

// By casting the following uses SubCmp
obj3 == b3 as Sub   // SubCmp is false
obj3 == b2 as Sub   // SubCmp is true
b2 as Sub == s1   // SubCmp is false

// It is illegal to cast a Base into a Sub
// obj3 == b1 as Sub     // Execution was interrupted...
```

Maybe it helps to summarise in the following points:

- If both variables are of type `Base` either by declaration (direct or indirectly) or casting, use `BaseCmp`
- If both variables are of type `Sub` either by declaration (direct or indirect or casting, use `SubCmp`
- If variables are of different types, use the common ground of `BaseCmp`

In my world, all these results are as expected, and I don't think it should be changed. One could possibly dream of using the most specified common ground when comparing `b2 == b3` since both actually holds a `Sub`, but I don't consider that to be a flaw in the language design.

Comment: Right, I understand how the current system works, but it seems to me that it makes the operator overloading system underpowered. In particular, I ran into an issue where I was writing a method that would accept two `Base` variables, and perform an operation on them if they were equal. However, as part of my program design, there were various subclasses to `Base` which I still wanted to call that method with. Given the static dispatch of operator functions, I am forced to write my own `.equals` method or something equivalent, when I would like to just use `==`.